# Match sequences of consecutive characters in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the string `"111221"` and want to match all sets of consecutive equal integers: `["111", "22", "1"]`.

I know that there is a special regex thingy to do that but I can't remember and I'm terrible at Googling.

Comment: What should happen when the input has non-digit characters, e.g. `"111aaa222"` and `"111aaa111"`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using regex in Ruby 1.8.7+:

```
p s.scan(/((\d)\2*)/).map(&:first)
#=> ["111", "22", "1"]
```

This works because `(\d)` captures any digit, and then `\2*` captures zero-or-more of whatever that group (the second opening parenthesis) matched. The outer `(…)` is needed to capture the entire match as a result in `scan`. Finally, `scan` alone returns:

```
[["111", "1"], ["22", "2"], ["1", "1"]]
```

…so we need to run through and keep just the first item in each array. In Ruby 1.8.6+ (which doesn't have `Symbol#to_proc` for convenience):

```
p s.scan(/((\d)\2*)/).map{ |x| x.first }
#=> ["111", "22", "1"]
```

With no Regex, here's a fun one (matching any char) that works in Ruby 1.9.2:

```
p s.chars.chunk{|c|c}.map{ |n,a| a.join }
#=> ["111", "22", "1"]
```

Here's another version that should work even in Ruby 1.8.6:

```
p s.scan(/./).inject([]){|a,c| (a.last && a.last[0]==c[0] ? a.last : a)<<c; a }
# => ["111", "22", "1"]
```

Comment: your "fun one" would match "00aa00" as ["000000"] - works on the sample input, but not on any non-trivial examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
"111221".gsub(/(.)(\1)*/).to_a
  #=> ["111", "22", "1"]
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) that does not have a block and therefore returns an enumerator. It appears `gsub` was bestowed with that option in v2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works, it first matches each character in one group, and then it matches any of the same character after it. This results in an array of two element arrays, with the first element of each array being the initial match, and then the second element being any additional repeated characters that match the first character. These arrays are joined back together to get an array of repeated characters:

```rb
input = "WWBWWWWBBBWWWWWWWB3333!!!!"
repeated_chars = input.scan(/(.)(\1*)/)
# => [["W", "W"], ["B", ""], ["W", "WWW"], ["B", "BB"], ["W", "WWWWWW"], ["B", ""], ["3", "333"], ["!", "!!!"]]
repeated_chars.map(&:join)
# => ["WW", "B", "WWWW", "BBB", "WWWWWWW", "B", "3333", "!!!!"]
```

As an alternative I found that I could create a new `Regexp` object to match one or more occurrences of each unique characters in the input string as follows:

```rb
input = "WWBWWWWBBBWWWWWWWB3333!!!!"
regexp = Regexp.new("#{input.chars.uniq.join("+|")}+")
#=> regexp created for this example will look like: /W+|B+|3+|!+/
```

and then use that `Regex` object as an argument for `scan` to split out all the repeated characters, as follows:

```rb
input.scan(regexp)
# => ["WW", "B", "WWWW", "BBB", "WWWWWWW", "B", "3333", "!!!!"]
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try is

```
string str ="111221";
string pattern =@"(\d)(\1)+";
```

Hope can help you

Comment: Downvoted because a) this doesn't work (you need `*` instead of `+`) and b) this isn't Ruby syntax, and doesn't work in Ruby even directly.