# Ruby: How can I split a string containing groups of consecutive letters into groups of those letters?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to turn a string containing groups of consecutive letters:

```rb
"aaabbbcccaaa"
```

Into:

```rb
["aaa","bbb","ccc","aaa"]
```

I'm sure this should be straight forward in Ruby but I'm stumped.

Comment: @Phrogz has given an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499054/5025116) a long time ago that might fit for your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str = "aaabbbcccaaa"

str.gsub(/(.)\1*/).to_a
  #=> ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa"]
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) that does not have a block and therefore returns an enumerator.

Comment: I understand the regex used here as: *match a single character followed by zero or more of the exact same match*. But what I don't understand is why this works in `#gsub` but not in `#scan`. If anyone could help me understand why, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It's simply because [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan) treats capture groups in a special way. See the doc. Is that clear? Sometimes it's useful that `scan` has that property; other times it gets in the way.

Comment: I just noticed I had enclosed `\1` in an unnecessary capture group. I don't know how that happened (or why someone else hasn't pointed that out), but I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Modified variant of [@Phrogz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499054/5025116)

```
"aaabbbcccaaa".scan(/((.)\2*)/).map(&:first) # => ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This variation should work on any string with groups of 2 consecutive characters

```
"foo\n\nbarr".gsub(/(.)(\1)*/).select{|l| l.length >1}
#=> ["oo", "rr"]
```

Or for alpha characters only:

```
"foo\n\n??barr..bazz".gsub(/([a-zA-Z])(\1)*/).select{|l| l.length >1}
#=> ["oo", "rr", "zz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly non-regex version:

```
str = "aaabbbcccaaa"
str.each_char.with_object([]) { |a,r| (r.last&.end_with?(a) ? r.last : r) << a }
=> ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do it without a regex using `Array#slice_when`:

```rb
"AAAABBBCDDD".chars.slice_when(&:!=).map(&:join)
#=> ["AAAA", "BBB", "C", "DDD"]
```

Though `gsub` with a regex (as suggested by Cary Swoveland in his answer) is clearly faster:

```
Benchmark.measure do
  100_000.times { "AAAABBBCDDD".chars.slice_when(&:!=).map(&:join) }  
end  

# => #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fb11ff9a560
#  @cstime=0.0,
#  @cutime=0.0,
#  @label="",
#  @real=1.427345999982208,
#  @stime=0.013876,
#  @total=1.3629069999999996,
#  @utime=1.3490309999999996>

Benchmark.measure do
  100_000.times { "AAAABBBCDDD".gsub(/(.)(\1)*/).to_a }
end

=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fb1214f4dc0
#  @cstime=0.0,
#  @cutime=0.0,
#  @label="",
#  @real=0.6837240000022575,
#  @stime=0.03575100000000003,
#  @total=0.64306,
#  @utime=0.6073089999999999>
```

Comment: Note that in my answer `/(.)\1*/` is sufficient. I don't know how that second capture group found its way into my original answer.